# symfony 1.1 sfNumberValidator plugin code in php

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have the validation check in validate/confirm.yml on the field postalCode as:

```
 postalCode:  
  required: yes
  required_msg: ENTER_VALID_POSTALCODE
  validators: numberValidator 

numberValidator:
  class: sfNumberValidator
  nan_error:    NOT_A_NUMBER_ERROR
```

for some reason i want to move the logic or same functionality of class sfNumberValidator in my action file.

like

```
class registerActions extends sfActions
{
    public function validateConfirm() {
            ....
            ...
        $postalCode = $this - > getRequestParameter('postalCode');

        if (postalCode != '') {

            //Do the same kind of validation like sfNumberValidator does 

        }

    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the `sfNumberValidator` instance and then call the `execute` method.

Something like this:

```
if ($postalCode != '') {

  $validator = new sfNumberValidator($this->getContext(), array(
           'nan_error' => 'Not a number',
           'min'       => 10000,
           'max'       => 99999
  ));
  $error = null;

  if(!$validator->execute($potalCode, $error)){
      //Here $error has the message you want to show the user
  }


}
```

PS: min and max are just a suggestion but you should maybe use something more explicit for you postal code case